# Wordpress: Form issues with checkbox

Tags: wordpress, forms, checkbox

i have a form, wrote in a page template:

```
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="merci">`
[... some inputs of different types: text, password, file ...]

<input type="checkbox" name="themes" value="$taxonomy_term_id"/> 
<label for="themes" > $term_name </label>

<input type="checkbox" name="themes" value="$taxonomy_term_id2"/> 
<label for="themes" > $term_name2 </label>

[...]

<input type="submit" />
</form>
```

The form is working good, but when i check some checkbox, after submitting, i got error 404 page not found ( the action page "merci" ). If no checkbox are checked, all work and i redirect to the "merci" page.

Any clue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="themes" value="$taxonomy_term_id"/> 
<label for="themes" > $term_name </label>

<input type="checkbox" name="themes" value="$taxonomy_term_id2"/> 
<label for="themes" > $term_name2 </label>
```

You have two checkboxes with the same `name=` attribute. Give them unique names.

Comment: Ok that's it, is there a way to have a group of checkbox with a unique key?

Comment: You might be looking for a radio button, not a checkbox. Dissect the source of this webpage to see how they work: http://www.htmldog.com/examples/inputcheckboxes.html

Comment: Just change `<input type="checkbox"` to `<input type="radio"` and your application should work. Make sure to have a default one selected.

Comment: Then they have to be unique. What are you trying to do with them?

Comment: Each checkbox is a taxonomy term (with term id as value), and add checked term to a page on submit.

Comment: Okay, that makes a bit more sense. You could give them name attributes with the term's name, like `themes_taxonomy_termNameGoesHere` and parse those submitted values with PHP.

Comment: Yes, i did it. But on all documentations, it's said that checkbox group can have same name attribut ( http://www.w3schools.com/html/html_forms.asp, same on all books i have ), strange isn't it?